# What is the best version of Ubuntu for an aging IBM T60 laptop?

Tags: versions

What is the best version/distro of Ubuntu for an aging IBM Thinkpad T60 laptop?

Comment: What are the HW specs on it? That is, how much RAM? How fast is the CPU?

Comment: It is a core Duo Centrino processor 1.83 Ghz with 2 GB RAM.

Comment: Thank you Eliah, I will check out your reference.  When I searched T60 and other keywords for helpful guidance before posting a new thread, it did not seem to return useful entries.  Perhaps my search terms were not the best since I'm new here.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend to use Lubuntu as a leightweight Ubuntu version for Netbooks or aging Laptops. what cpu speed does your T60 has? there are many versions.

you can download and read about from this page :

[Lubuntu](http://www.lubuntu.net/)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, definitely will look into it some more though think I prefer a more robust version.  Processor speed is 1.83 Ghz.

Answer (score 0):

I have and use an aging T60 laptop with your exact specs. I use and recommend Ubuntu 13.04 using Unity. If you have corrupted attributes on you harddrive, I suggest you replace it. It is quite easy to do in a T60.

Answer (score 0):

I’m running ubuntu 13.04 (which is the latest version) on the following :
CPU : Intel Pentium 4 3Ghz
RAM : 1GB

I know it's very slow but it works fine if you are using for internet or movie and entertainment